# Net-ssh timeout for execution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, net-ssh

In my application I want to terminate the `exec!` command of my SSH connection after a specified amount of time.

I found the `:timeout` for the `Net::SSH.start` command but following the documentation this is only for the initial connection. Is there something equivalent for the `exec` command?

My first guess would be not using `exec!` as this will wait until the command is finished but using `exec` and surround the call with a loop that checks the execution status with every iteration and fails after the given amount of time.

Something like this, if I understood the documentation correctly:

```
server = NET::SSH.start(...)

server.exec("some command")

start_time = Time.now
terminate_calculation = false

trap("TIME") { terminate_calculation = ((Time.now - start_time) > 60) }
ssh.loop(0.1) { not terminate_calculation }
```

However this seems dirty to me. I expect something like `server.exec("some command" { :timeout=>60})`. Maybe there is some built in function for achieving this functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if this would actually work in a SSH context but Ruby itself has a timeout method:

```
server = NET::SSH.start ...
timeout 60 do
  server.exec! "some command"
end
```

This would raise `Timeout::Error` after 60 seconds. Check out [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html).

Comment: I would not recommend this https://jvns.ca/blog/2015/11/27/why-rubys-timeout-is-dangerous-and-thread-dot-raise-is-terrifying/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a native way to do it in net/ssh. See [the code](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/master/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb#L319), there's no additional parameter for that option.

One way would be to handle timeouts in the command you call - see [this answer on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43340/how-to-introduce-timeout-for-shell-scripting).

I think your way is better, as you don't introduce external dependencies in the systems you connect to.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to set ConnectTimeout option in OpenSSH configuration files (~/.ssh/config, /etc/ssh_config, ...)

Check more info in

https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/master/lib/net/ssh/config.rb

Answer (score 0):

what I did is have a thread that's doing the event handling. Then I loop for a defined number of seconds until channel closed.If after these seconds pass, the channel is still open, then close it and continue execution.